# Autocomplete action parses a large JSON file at each ajax call (make it faster)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ajax, ruby-on-rails-4, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am trying to make an autocomplete model for cities and zipcode using Rails 4 and Jquery ui.
I have a large JSON file (about 500,000 lines) that contains an array (cp_autocomplete) that contains zipcode (CP) and cities (CITY).

In my current model, on every ajax query the autocomplete action reads the JSON file, parses it and then search for a zipcode or city, makes a list of nine zipcode+cities (if found) and render the list as json.

This works but it makes more than 2 seconds to render a list.

Any ideas to make it runs faster?
- How could I parse the json file once and not on every ajax query?
- I thought of caching the parsed json value and then delete it after 1 minute for example.

Here is my autocomplete action:

```
    def autocomplete
      require 'auto_compeletion_cp_city' #a class that has PostalCode and City attributes
    postal_file = File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/postal_code_fr.json")
    postal_parse = JSON.parse(postal_file)
    @list = []
    if !(ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(params[:Postalcode]).blank?)
      search_term = ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(params[:Postalcode])
      search = /\A#{search_term}/
          postal_parse["cp_autocomplete"].each do |f|
            if search.match("#{f['CP']}",0) && (@list.length < 9)
              selected = AutoCompletionCpCity.new
              selected.PostalCode = f['CP']
              selected.City = f['CITY']
              @list << selected
            end
          end
    else
      if !(ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(params[:city]).blank?)
      search_term = ActionController::Base.helpers.sanitize(params[:city])
      search = /\A#{Regexp.escape(search_term)}/i
      postal_parse["cp_autocomplete"].each do |f|
            if search.match("#{f['CITY']}",0) && (@list.length < 9) 
              selected = AutoCompletionCpCity.new
              selected.PostalCode = f['CP']
              selected.City = f['CITY']
              @list << selected
            end
       end
      end
    end

    respond_to do |format|
      format.json { 
        render json: @list
      }
    end
  end
```

Comment: Just an idea have you try a database solution? Or maybe something like Redis to replace the file? I often use this solution for autocomplete select field with ajax and select 2 but I never tried on something with 500,000 lines.

Comment: I'm working on Redis solution.. I'll let you know if it does better..
For the database solution would you save the data as a json array or make a new sql database?
I'm using sqlite3 for development

Comment: Presumably if you have a rails app you have a database already?  I would make a table (or maybe a couple of tables) to hold the data in this text file.

Comment: I never try to achieve this with json or hstore (I mainly work with Postgres). But few of my ajax call are made on a traditional db, I require a min of 3 character before sending the first call. For my usage it's pretty fast. I think the redis solution in your case would be interesting. I see a project for the elections which use this solution to find your election bureau from you zipcode, it was amazingly fast and there was a lot of simultaneous connexions.

Comment: @Max Williams by SQL database I meant SQL table.
+coding addict Nice. I require a min of 3 characters also and 500ms of delay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a small module to house the postal code data. It can parse the file once when the process starts and hold onto it forever. Since postal codes don't change often (and this file is in your repo, so changing it requires a deploy), there's no reason to cache for just 1 minute.

```
module PostalCodes
  DATA = JSON.parse(File.read("#{Rails.root}/public/postal_code_fr.json"))
end
```

This module can also be responsible for searching the codes and other behavior you need.

Before you get too deep in this, as with all performance optimization, you should verify the part of your code that's causing search to take 2 seconds. If it's the JSON parsing, caching the data will help, but if it's running a regular expression over ever postal code, you need a different solution.

Comment: You're right. I can keep the cache.. Maybe I can make this Data in an initializer?
Any suggestion for the postal code search.. It's not the best solution I know

Comment: Yep, you could certainly put this in an initializer. For prefix searches, [Tries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie) are an excellent structure. Getting this data into your DB is also a good option.

Comment: By making the cache solution, the response time for an ajax request drop down to 200 ms with a rails execution time of 66 ms. http://img15.hostingpics.net/pics/279561RailsView.png
Is it worth it to go for the Tries algorithm?

Comment: Totally your call, only depends how fast you want it. Sounds like a lot of your time is now network though. Even eliminating time in Rails will leave you with 140ms.

Comment: Just to give a feedback after making a prefix search on redis.. The rails response become less than 10 ms.. http://www.hostingpics.net/viewer.php?id=358401rails.png